# Xray 3.x Uninstall document

Tags: jfrog-xray

Do you know where is a JFrog Xray 3.x uninstall document? I found this document (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY2X/Uninstalling+Xray ), but the url contains 2x version.

Bst regards,
Takoneko

Comment: Did you find it out?